# COVID-19 - Is it okay to send emails this time for post-doc position?

Tags: postdocs

I will be submitting my Ph.D. thesis in the comming two months. From last one month I was sending email to professors for post-doc position but from last week I have stopped sending emails requesting for post-doc position due COVID -19. Although the impact of this virus in my country is less. I am in a confusion whether or not to send an email regarding post-doc position at this time?

Comment: Why not? What is alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, by all means keep looking for a position. The future is unknown. Things may settle down or not, but it would be a mistake to wait until they do before you even begin a search. But email responses may be slower than usual and people may need to be more tentative. Expect that.

I suspect things will be hard for a while, but no one expects it to be permanent.

You can't win the game if you don't play.

Comment: Is it okay to email multiple potential supervisors for post-doc position?

Comment: Yes, fine now, as always. Good luck.